# 400 Bad Request Error , Angular4+

Tags: angular, service

[image]

I am trying to fetch data from the database. 
I am able to log in, but not able to retrieve data from the database.
However, testing via Postman returns a status 200.

[image]

This is my API call index  :

```
export let CONTEXTROOT="http://localhost:8080/core/api/";
```

This is my getDashboardData() function :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable,pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CONTEXTROOT } from '../contextRoot';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  // for debugging

/**
 * This class provides the Data service with methods to get and post data.
 */
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  /**
   * Creates a new DataService with the injected Http.
   * @param {Http} http - The injected Http.
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
   * @return {string[]} The Observable for the HTTP request.
   */
  getDashBoardData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(CONTEXTROOT+'dashboard')
    //              .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

This is my Error Handling Function :

```
    private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Why am I not enable to Fetch the Data? I have CORS Plugin in Chrome Enabled as well.

Comment: Please check if `/core/api/dashboard` web service accepts some kind of data. Because a bad request usually occurs when the data that the API expects is not passed or the type of data is wrong.

Comment: yes. it is working via POSTMAN. it's a GET Request, I get a status 200.

Comment: Are you sending some extra data or a header in your request?

Comment: First, you're mixing old operators (.do) and old factory methods (.throw) with new pipeable operators. Don't do that. Stick to pipeable operators (tap()), and to standalong factory function (throw, imported from rxjs). Now, regarding the 400 error, we can't tell why your **server** sends that back. Read the server source code or documentation to find out.

Comment: no extra data or headers. just the CORS plugin is enabled

Comment: So maybe because of CORS, it is happening. Try adding the same header in Postman which your web call in the browser is adding and let us know.

Comment: @JBNizet the do function is commented out. i am getting back the data via POSTMAN , all i am doing is passing 1 Header , Key->Authorization , Value-> Bearer Token

Comment: @AnkitSharma  i am getting back the data via POSTMAN , all i am doing is passing 1 Header , Key->Authorization , Value-> Bearer Token

Comment: Are there any `access-control-allow-origin` or something like those headers being sent in the request header. Please check.

Comment: @codemt focus on the other parts of my comment, then.

Comment: @JBNizet yes I get that. actually, this project is being developed by some other developers. my work is just to do QC and stuff. however, it's a pain to work on someone's else's code who maybe 10 miles away somewhere you don't even know. Anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: If the developer didn't bother to add an error body to the response explaining why you get that error, then ask **that** developer. We can't help.

Comment: @JBNizet i am able to do the login bro , login and logout CORS request works , then how come not other requests.  yes will ask the developer.

Comment: If it's not explained in the error response body, then, once again, you, or the other developer, needs to look in the **server** source code. We can't guess why a server does something by looking at the client code. CORS shouldn't have anything to do with this. If it was a CORS problem, the browser would prevent you from sending your request.